# What if I develop my own hash algorithm to create strong passwords from easy ones (for Gmail, Skype etc)?

Tags: algorithm, hash, passwords

I came up with this idea but I cant figure out if it's good or bad, maybe you can help. 
My goal is: I want to create extremely strong passwords for my main accounts (gmail, skype and so on). I want to have different passwords for all my accounts that are longer than 20 characters and that contains lower+upper case chars, numbers and special characters. What would you do to achieve that?

It's pretty impossibile to remember even one password like that so I came up with this idea: what if I develop a (simple and secret) hashing algorithm that transforms easy passwords (even 3 or 4 characters) into strong ones?

In that scenario I would only have to remember "dog" for my Gmail, "black" for  Yahoo and so on. When you have to login, you just process your easy password in your handmade script that converts it, than you just copy-paste.

I think this method is great for some reasons:

- if your hashing algo is irreversible and secret, there's no way to figure out the "easy passwords" by having (even a lot) of the strong passwords (anyway you must be really unlucky if someone managed to hack all your main accounts on gmail, forums, instant messaging and so on)
- i just have to remember extremely easy words for all my accounts while my "final passwords" will be bulletproof for lots of years
- if well made, an easy hashing algo can just be remembered and used on paper instead of making a script (that could be eventually stolen). the algorithm can be easy because you dont need an extremely good avalanche effect (you won't be making tens of thousands of passwords, maybe just 100 or 200 in a few years?

Even if a cracker managed to understand the formulas in your hashing algorithm, there are no public rainbow tables for your algorithm, and I highly doubt that your gmail account is so valuable that anyone would start making one. This method is meant only for everyday passwords, not for high risk situations where NSA is involved, and it is good because the algoritm is related only to YOUR passwords, because it's not a public one. MD5 is used by thousands of websites, that's why people started wasting time/money to crack it. My personal algo will be just mine, so noone will be interested to invest money to crack it

What's your opinion?

PS. sorry of my extremely bad english :)

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable here. Maybe on http://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Just a comment : instead of protecting a password (stored in your head), you'd now have to protect a program (probably stored in many places as you can't afford to lose it). This doesn't look very secure.

Comment: What if you could make a hash algorithm so easy it could be calculated with a pen and paper? It could be easy because you dont need the extreme security provided by SHA&co, because you will be the only user of that code  (I'm thinking about some XOR operations, mod operations, and so on)

Comment: Well... this starts to look like what some (many?) coders do and don't publicize. Hint : you can include the target as a salt in your function. ;)

Comment: Your idea sounds reasonable to me. It is probably cumbersome when you have to access your accounts via smartphone or tablet and not only from a PC.

Comment: Checkout http://blog.danskingdom.com/create-unique-strong-passwords-that-are-easy-to-remember-for-all-your-accounts-without-using-a-password-manager/. Similar idea, but no software required.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not the worst, but the problems are obvious (you mentioned them yourself).

1. The whole security depends on the fact that the algorithm remains secret. This is maybe not a problem in your case, but it can *become* a problem in future (depending on what you are protecting).
2. If the script is known, the "security by obscurity" is gone, that means an attacker has only to brute force *weak* passwords anymore.

In my opinion the main disadvantage is, that you have to start your script whenever you need to enter a password (otherwise it's more like a password scheme). If you take it upon you to start a tool everytime, you could just as easily start a password manager tool like:

http://keepass.info/

Such tools can be put on USB-sticks and you have the advantage that you can use really strong passwords, and that you don't even need to invent/remember weak passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea but it's been done already. Checkout [PasswordMaker](http://www.passwordmaker.org/passwordmaker.html). There's an online version and it is available as an extension. One cool thing is your master password doesn't have to vary with the website. It can be the same but according to the Input URL it spits out different passwords. And like you mention, the length of the generated password is configurable and you can choose which hash algorithm to apply.